# Ckeditor can not create new profile with input format

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, input-formats

I've already a profile with input types but I can not create another, even when I am cloning the profile with input types.

These are my text format, and I using administrator user.
[image]

This is the list of ckeditor profiles
[image]

In Test profile, the only text format allowed is PHP code.
[image]

What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem when creating or cloning a ckeditor profile, the module doesn't insert registers into the table **ckeditor_input_format**, so we can do that by the following SQL queries

```
INSERT INTO `ckeditor_input_format` (name, format) VALUES ('<profile_name>','filtered_html')
INSERT INTO `ckeditor_input_format` (name, format) VALUES ('<profile_name>','full_html')
INSERT INTO `ckeditor_input_format` (name, format) VALUES ('<profile_name>','plain_text')
```

The name  must be replaced with the name of the profile you created with ckeditor.